# PHP Session not passing

Tags: php, session, amazon-ec2

Our problem is that php keeps making new sessions on every refresh or page redirect. It makes a reference file in "/var/lib/php/7.0/session/" on every refresh, so it does make a file with the correct data in it for that page.

We are using an EC2 instance that runs red hat linux. We were using php 5.6 and upgraded to php 7.0 to try and resolve a possible timeout issue.
We have looked through lots of threads. SO let me rule those out first

Error reporting:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

We have error checking on. It's not file permissions, I went as far as making it 777 and the groups are Apache. We did try to change the session_save_path and had no effect to the problem

Session start/check in initialize.php:

```
if(session_id() == ''){
   //session has not started
   session_start();
}
```

Every page starts with:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/../restricted/initialize.php");
```

We have tried on multiply pc's, same result.

Comment: Sounds like PHP doesn't get a session ID from the browser. Are you using conflicting methods or names for that?

Comment: Are you guys using Amazon Elb? If yes you have to configure the stick session or session affinity. Take a look at the aws elb documentation or if you prefer you can implement using Aws Elastic Cache.